# Team Foundation Server - Administration > WIT Editor (Task) - Activity specific tabs

Tags: tfs

In Team Foundation Server 2012, using WIT Editor for the Task type, I'm trying to show/hide tabs based on the Activity field value of the task. Is this possible?

- Activity: **Design** => **Design Review** tab *shown*, Code Review tab *hidden* (see *Image1*)
- Activity: **Develop** => **Design Review** tab *hidden*, Code Review tab *shown* (see *Image2*)

*Image1*
[Activity: Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7cyQ.png)

*Image2*
[Activity: Develop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWP29.png)

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, however you can probably set the controls on the tabs to be readonly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Betty. Please advise how I could make the controls readonly.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528496/how-can-i-prohibit-state-change-from-proposed-to-active-in-tfs-requirement-work  it shows the xml needed to make a field readonly on a certain condition

Comment: Hi, Betty. I've made it turn fields READONLY with your suggestion, thank you for suggesting this alternative, it's a feasible workaround (a little bit more work to have to do this for each field in those tabs + the fact tabs will still take screen real estate when not applicable).

Comment: BTW, I suggested this to MSFT on User Voice [TFS 2012 - WIT Editor (Task) - Activity specific tabs](http://uservoice.com/a/YC3Q9) - what do you think?